# Multiple tables in one SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hey guys I've been looking for a topic about how to create 2 tables in same project ? 
Would you guys please give me some example or some links for me to look for it :)

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CAS_DB";
public static final String tbPerson = "PersonInfo";
public static final String tbColor = "ColorInfo";
```

what I want is create 2 tables in one database but I can't find any example

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Mint..If you know to work with single table creation,then you can go with same process for next as usual...

Comment: you need to give more details around your use case and how you are creating the db/tables.

Comment: I have the same question.
However, I do know that it doesn't matter about the semicolons at the end of the SQL statements. A semicolon is used to separate SQL statement/commands. In this case you are just implementing one command at a time, so it won't matter if it's included or not.

Answer (score 6):

```
private static final String PERSON_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + tbPerson +
                    " (" +
                    PERSON_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    PERSON_NAME + " TEXT);";
private static final String COLOR_TABLE_CREATE =
                    "CREATE TABLE " + tbColor +
                    " (" +
                    COLOR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLOR_NAME + " TEXT);";
```

And in onCreate method of your database helper:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(PERSON_TABLE_CREATE);
            mDatabase.execSQL(COLOR_TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the statements should not have ; (semicolons) at the end for the execSQL to work.

Comment: I am also not sure, but in this [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) semicolons are used.

Comment: what if table B has a many relationship with table A? How do you go about setting the foreign key in Table B?

Comment: @jamapag, how to upgrade the table. The `onUpgrade()` takes three args  - `SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion`. How to use it if I have to upgrade only one table and the second table is untouched.